# What does |= mean in c++?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to understand |= in c++, I have sample code

```
 int x = 0 ;

 x |= 3;
 std::cout<<x <<std::endl;

 x |= 6;
 std::cout<<x <<std::endl;
```

output is :

```
3
7
```

how is this possible, is it related to bit addition??

Comment: You could have answered this by looking at a list of C++ operators and then googling the name.

Comment: What you are referring to is a bitwise OR operator. It compares all the bits then the result contains the most significant bit (1, 0) of the two operands. For example:
`1111000 | 0000111 = 1111111`
**It is not a bit addition**, try x = 72 | 184 ==> x = 248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bitwise OR.

**First** case:

```
0011(3 in decimal)
0000(0 in decimal)
```

So, the OR of both is:

```
0011 OR 0000 = 0011

= 2^0 + 2^1 
= 3
```

For **second** case, the OR works as follows:

```
0011 (3 in decimal) 
0110 (6 in decimal)
```

Output of OR is 0111 which in decimal is:

```
0011 OR 0110 = 0111

= 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 
= 1+2+4 
= 7
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a bitwise or and assignment. It is the same as x = x | 3.

In binary bitwise or is equivalent to "if it's a 1 in either number it will be a 1 in the result". So x |= 3 makes 3. Then x is 11 in binary and 6 is 110 in binary so 11 | 101 = 111 (binary) = 7 (decimal).

Answer (score 4):

```
x |= 3
```

means

```
x = x |3
```

bitwise or operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is bitwise

> OR

and then assignment. This means the same as `x = x | 3`.
[about bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)